# Webstorm: is it possible to debug a Meteor application directly in Chrome DevTools' console, instead of Webstorm GUI?

Tags: meteor, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

As the title says,

I see it is possible to debug a Meteor application in Webstorm but I can't figure out **how to do the debug directly on Chrome DevTools**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get into CDT, mash F12 in the browser window.

Then, you can select the "Sources" tab, followed by the .js file you want to inspect, and at a breakpoint by clicking on the line of code you're currently interested in. e.g., this screamshot shows a breakpoint in a template's "events" section:

[image]

As you can see, there are many other tools CDT allows you; poke around, experiment, research, and you will find a wealth of valuable insight.

Besides Chrome, Firefox also has good debugging tools, and probably most other browsers, too, including Microsoft's new Edge browser. AFAIK, they are all invoked via F12.

Comment: I actually found the answer by myself but forgot to update my question. thank for the effort!

Answer (score 2):

You can debug the client code using Chrome DevTools by just opening Chrome DevTools while viewing localhost:3000.

I'm not aware of a way to use Chrome DevTools for server-side debugging, but you can debug from Chrome via Node Inspector. For details, type `meteor help debug` and follow the directions.

Comment: I actually found the answer by myself but forgot to update my question. thank for the effort!